# castle windsor does not resolve float values

Tags: c#, dictionary, castle-windsor, castle

i have dictionary configured in castle windsor config, where key type is **string** and value type is **float**:

```
<dictionary keyType="System.String, mscorlib" valueType="System.Single, mscorlib">
                    <entry key="First">5,3</entry>
                    <entry key="Second">5,6</entry>
                    <entry key="Third">5,95</entry>
                </dictionary>
```

The problem is that in C# code i get value types resolved into:

```
First: 53
Second: 56
Third: 595
```

Anyone familiar with this case?

Comment: Try using full stop (`.`) instead of comma.

Comment: yes, you were right. different globalization settings - different float number separator